# Create class for svg icons to use it in blazor projects

Tags: c#, svg, blazor, mudblazor

I have downloaded some .svg files from svgrepo website. I want to use them in mudblazor project with the class name.

```
<MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Share" Disabled="true" aria-label="share"> </MudIconButton>
```

Svg icon downloaded from [svgrepo](https://www.svgrepo.com/vectors/sms/)

```
<svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" 
class="icon"  version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M789.333333 
832H234.666667l-128 
128V234.666667c0-70.4 57.6-128 128-128h554.666666c70.4 0 128 57.6 
128 128v469.333333c0 
70.4-57.6 128-128 128z" fill="#009688" /><path d="M512 469.333333m- 
64 0a64 64 0 1 0 128 0 
64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z" fill="#FFFFFF" /><path d="M725.333333 
469.333333m-64 0a64 64 0 1 0 
128 0 64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z" fill="#FFFFFF" /><path d="M298.666667 
469.333333m-64 0a64 64 0 
1 0 128 0 64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z" fill="#FFFFFF" /></svg>
```

I want to use the SVG icon I download from the svgrepo site Like `Icon="@Mydownloadedicon"`

how can I implement it?

Haven't found any rescources, so I wasn't able to try anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove  `width` and `height` attribute from svg and Create Class as follows:

```
public class MyICons
{
    public const string CustomIcon = "<svg  viewBox=\"0 0 1024 1024\" \r\nclass=\"icon\"  version=\"1.1\" \r\nxmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><path d=\"M789.333333 \r\n832H234.666667l-128 \r\n128V234.666667c0-70.4 57.6-128 128-128h554.666666c70.4 0 128 57.6 \r\n128 128v469.333333c0 \r\n70.4-57.6 128-128 128z\" fill=\"#009688\" /><path d=\"M512 469.333333m- \r\n64 0a64 64 0 1 0 128 0 \r\n64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\" /><path d=\"M725.333333 \r\n469.333333m-64 0a64 64 0 1 0 \r\n128 0 64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\" /><path d=\"M298.666667 \r\n469.333333m-64 0a64 64 0 \r\n1 0 128 0 64 64 0 1 0-128 0Z\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\" /></svg>";
}
```

and use like this :

```
<MudIconButton Icon="@MyICons.CustomIcon" Disabled="true" aria-label="share"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways you can implement this.

1. Create a string with the `SVG` content and add that to the Icon.

```
    <MudIcon Icon="@cube" Color="Color.Primary" />

@code{
        const string cube = @"<svg style=""width:24px;height:24px"" viewBox=""0 0 24 24"">
    <path fill=""currentColor"" d=""M21,16.5C21,16.88 20.79,17.21 20.47,17.38L12.57,21.82C12.41,21.94 12.21,22 12,22C11.79,22 11.59,21.94 11.43,21.82L3.53,17.38C3.21,17.21 3,16.88 3,16.5V7.5C3,7.12 3.21,6.79 3.53,6.62L11.43,2.18C11.59,2.06 11.79,2 12,2C12.21,2 12.41,2.06 12.57,2.18L20.47,6.62C20.79,6.79 21,7.12 21,7.5V16.5M12,4.15L6.04,7.5L12,10.85L17.96,7.5L12,4.15M5,15.91L11,19.29V12.58L5,9.21V15.91M19,15.91V9.21L13,12.58V19.29L19,15.91Z"" />
</svg>";
}
```

2. Create a separate razor component which renders the SVG content. Then you can simply import and use that component.

Have a look at snippet for both methods demos.
[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOGRETwThOmXvmnu)